# Plone theming with Bootstrap. native theme or Diazo

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, plone

As a base for making my own "personalized" Plone theme based on Bootstrap:

What are the pros and cons of
the "native" plonetheme.boostrap (which I suppose is going to be the new default theme for Plone 5)

https://github.com/collective/plonetheme.bootstrap

versus the different diazo-based Bootstrap approaches?

e g https://github.com/veit/vs.bootstrap.plonetheme

I might even need to buy a theme design for Boostrap at some place like wrapbootstrap.com or 99designs.com

I aim for Boostrap 3.x and Plone 4.3.2

(I have followed Plone since its start as a Zope skin and used for years with small customzations it with minor theming since 2003 on a few non-profit community sites that I provide. In 2011/2012 I wrote, out of necessity, a Plone 4-based conference web and registration system for a conference I hosted. Lots of z3c.form's with MySql and some Dexterity)

Comment: If you read at http://plone.org/news/cathedral-sprint-report you will see that the plone 5 theme is not plonetheme.boostrap but Barceloneta

Comment: Ok, I remember seeing a reference in passing to Bootstrap being part of the planned front-end stack for Plone 5. I now understand that it might have been part of a discussion/debate instead of something firmly decided.

Comment: If Bootstrap, unlike Jquery, will never be included in the basic theming, this answers what I guess is my root question. If I put effort into a Boostrap theme, native or Diazo-based, I will not as easily end up with all 10 fingers and 10 toes plugging conflicts between layers of theming and versions.

Answer (score 2):

imho, actually skin with diazo both front-end and back-end could be waste of time.
I prefer to heavy-customize the front-end with diazo (based on bootstrap) living the back-end with Sunburst Theme (maybe with some css tricks).

This approach for "authentic" plone editors should be trivial, cause they are accustomed to the (fantastic) WYSWYG plone's way. But if you're building a project where editors come from joomla/wordpress/typo3(etc) shouldn't be a problem cause this CMSs use different skins for front/back end.

Vito

Comment: The problem with this approach (that is right IMHO) is that can't be applied to every situations. For example: when using Plone for an intranet you can't have a separate layout.

Comment: It will only be edited by myself and maybe a few helpers when we have community events. Plone is very useful to delegate responsibility for content to groups of volunteers. (My plone sites run on different VMs in my basement ganeti setup.)